# Find word in string and split string from that word

Tags: javascript

I have this string :

```
var str = "select field1,field2,field3 from Table1";
```

In above string I want to extract all items before from keyword and get output in array like below :

```
field1
field2
field3
```

But I am getting true value in my data variable **so I can't split data variable further by comma.**

```js
var str = "select field1,field2,field3 from Table1";
var outputArr = [];

 var data =  str.split(' ').some(function(w){return w === 'from'});
 
 console.log(data);
```

Comment: you want *find* instead of *some* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "select field1,field2,field3 from Table1".split(" ");
var data=  str[str.indexOf("from")-1];//get the element that is right before the from
console.log(data.split(","));
```

Alternatively, with more advanced options:

```
var str = "select field1,field2,field3 from Table1".split(" ");
var data=  str[str.findIndex(el=>el.toLowerCase()==="from")-1];//get the element that is right before the from
console.log(data.split(","));
```

Note that some is meant to check for existence of sth, so it returns either true or false...

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but what if from is like this : From or FROM or from?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice()` from 1 to `indexOf` element with value `from` and then split by comma.

```js
var str = "select field1,field2,field3 from Table1";
var arr = str.split(' ')

var result = arr.slice(1, arr.indexOf('fRoM'.toLowerCase()))[0].split(',')
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but what if from is like this : From or FROM or from?

Comment: Add `toLowerCase` on your input string.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work for you.

```
var fromIndex = str.indexOf(' from ');
/*you can put 7 statically because select is exactly 6 letters and consider a space after it*/
str.substring(7,fromIndex).split(',');
```

More short hand syntax

```
str.substring(7,str.indexOf(' from ')).split(',');
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but what if from is like this : From or FROM or from?

Comment: `str.substring(7,str.toLowerCase().indexOf(' from ')).split(',');` this will make the fix

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well:

```
str.toLowerCase().split('select')[1].split('from')[0].replace(/ /g,'').split(',')
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but what if from is like this : From or FROM or from?